# Use Shift-Left (shl) to get 2^N, given N?

Tags: assembly, x86, multiplication, bit-shift

Trying to use Shift-Left instruction for multiplication.

The `SHL`  (shift left) instruction performs a logical left shift on the destination operand, filling the lowest bit with 0.

[image: SHL instruction]

I don't understand how to use register or memory for N, because when I attempt to do so, I am told "invalid instruction operand"

1. The user inputs a number N in the RequestNumber procedure (which returns `EAX`).
2. The calculation I am attempting is: result = 1 * 2^N

**My code:**

```
mov ebx, 1   
call RequestNumber      ; returns eax   
shl ebx, eax   
mov result, ebx
```

The assignment I am working on requests to use the Shift to get result = 2^N
As far as I've seen, you can only use imm8 numbers with this register `CL` (tried using the lower `ECX` with the same result).

[image: Operand types for SHL]

**Question:
How do I properly use the Shift instruction if I have to get N from the user?**

Comment: If it's really inconvenient to use `cl` for the shift count, and your CPU has the BMI2 instructions, you could use [`shlx`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/sarx:shlx:shrx). Larger code size though (5 bytes versus 2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shift amount has to be in `cl`.  So to get shift input from the user, place it in `cl`.  Recall that `cl` is the low 8 bit of `ecx`, so if you place the shift amount in `ecx` and then shift by `cl`, it works as expected:

```
mov ebx, 1   
call RequestNumber      ; returns eax
mov ecx, eax
shl ebx, cl
mov result, ebx
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I was struggling to understand how to "move" a value from a bigger EAX to a smaller CL register

Comment: @urmur I understand.  For the record, the trick is to move from the corresponding smaller register of the source to the destination.  E.g. to move from `eax` to `cl`, do `mov cl, al`.  Alternatively, do `mov ecx, eax` or `movzx ecx, al`. Which one to use depends on what you want to happen with the upper bits of the destination.

Comment: Note that there's another way to implement `1<<n` which is slightly more efficient on Intel CPUs: `xor edx, edx` / `bts edx, eax` (EDX |= 1<<EAX).  It doesn't need the count in CL specifically, and xor-zeroing is at least as cheap as `mov reg, 1`.  BTS on AMD CPUs is 2 uops, so it's about break even by saving the `mov ecx,eax`. 
 (You don't want memory-destination BTS with a register bit-index, it's much slower.  https://agner.org/optimize/)